# grep and tee to identify errors during installation

Tags: linux, grep, tee

In order to identify if my installation has errors that I should notice, I am using grep command on the file and write the file using tee because I need to elevate permissions.

```
sudo grep -inw ${LOGFOLDER}/$1.log -e "failed" | sudo tee -a ${LOGFOLDER}/$1.errors.log
sudo grep -inw ${LOGFOLDER}/$1.log -e "error" | sudo tee -a ${LOGFOLDER}/$1.errors.log
```

The thing is that the file is created even if the grep didn't find anything.
Is there any way I can create the file only if the grep found a match ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may replace `tee` with `awk`, it won't create file if there is nothing to write to it:

```
... | sudo awk "{print; print \$0 >> \"errors.log\";}"
```

But such feature of awk is rarely used. I'd rather remove empty error file if nothing is found:

```
test -s error.log || rm -f error.log
```

And, by the way, you may grep for multiple words simultaneously:

```
grep -E 'failed|error' ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also for the advice with grep multiple words search :)

Comment: Thanks. Multiple search done: sudo grep -E "failed|error" -inw ${LOGFOLDER}/$1.log and works great. The awk command returns me an error:     sudo grep -E "failed|error" -inw ${LOGFOLDER}/$1.log | sudo awk "{print; print $0 >> '${LOGFOLDER}/$1.errors.log';}"
returns: awk: cmd. line:1: {print; print -bash >> 'errors.log';}
awk: cmd. line:1:                        ^ invalid char ''' in expression
awk: cmd. line:1: {print; print -bash >> 'errors.log';}
awk: cmd. line:1:                        ^ syntax error

Comment: Quotation marks need to be escaped: `"{print; print \$0 >> \"${LOGFOLDER}/$1.errors.log\";}"`